# Horizontal align not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, alignment

My site seems to perfectly runnning on Google Chrome but when it is viewed in Firefox or IE, The alignment it completely awkward. Can somebody please help me sort this issue.
Thanx in advance.

The link to the website is :

The problem with firefox/IE is that the 3 boxes are not aligned in the middle.
where as in chrome it is aligned to the center which is exactly what i want.

Regards

Comment: Please post some code or at least a link to your problematic page!

Comment: Please add a description of exactly what isn't showing up correctly.  Viewing it in Firefox 4 it appears ok.

Comment: @Scunliffe - check it in chrome once, the 3 boxes(1. news 2. consisting image saying 'Roboshaala' & 'School Robotics' 3. Consisting of image saying 'Internship' & 'My RoboBazaar')

Comment: No offense, but you're dumping us a commercial site you're developing - presumably for money. Why should you earn money for problems we fix? (Please not, we're absolutely fine with commercial questions if sufficiently reduced or tackled by the original submitter.)

Comment: I don't get it. I've just checked in Chrome 10 and Firefox 4 and they both look exactly the same.

Comment: Ok, the alignment is close, but the Internship label definitely seems off.  Viewing the source there's a lot going on so its a bit hard to tell.  I'd recommend removing all the extra HTML comments, and spaces after `img` tags that are wrapped in `a` link tags.  I'd also recommend changing many of your `id` attributes to start with a letter, and try to avoid resizing images in HTML (it tends to distort them).  These may not fix the issue but may help clear up the code and make it easier to see the actual issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your content box is inline-block; and is floated left.

make it block `display:block`, align to the center `margin:0 auto;` and remove float.
I think this should help.

and same for other boxes as well

Comment: LOL..i know that shota..was jus trying to find the line. I've foud that line nevertheless..but the shanges havent helped..its the same...

Comment: also check Gaby-s post you've got some tags opening/closing problem so this will cause problems too.

Answer (score 0):

You have a case of bad nesting of opening/closing divs.

you need to comment out the `</div>` after  the

```
<!-- .. END OF THE CONTENT .. -->
```

comment.

When there are problems in your HTML, each browser will attempt to fix it, but in a non standardized way.

Answer (score 0):

if you reduce the `#frontcontent-container` rule in style.css to just read:

```
#frontcontent-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 960px;    
}
```

that should do the trick. the problem is you're floating left and displaying as inline-block. Also, it seems you're including the stylesheet twice.

Oh and there seems to be some problems with your markup - the wrapper div doesn't actually wrap much at all, so i assume you're missing a closing tag somewhere!